# Google drive exclusive file locking

Tags: file-sharing, google-drive

Is there a way to acquire an exclusive lock for files in Google Drive to prevent concurrent modifications?

I'm helping a friend to set up their small business office, and they need to be able to share and collaborate on Autocad (binary) files. GSuite Google Drive seems to fit most of their use cases (like permissions on file/folder levels, sharing with people outside the business etc.) apart from this one thing: AFAIK google drive will sync files locally on each user's device, meaning that two people maybe working on the same file at the same time without being aware that someone else is also working on it so changes from one of them might be lost. My feeling is this problem could be overcome with something like exclusive file locking from users, but I can't seem to find anything similar for Google Drive. Am I thinking about this the right way?

Thank you

PS. other solutions that were proposed but rejected:

- Use Azure File store + Azure AD DS but rejected because of costs
- Use Autodesk Vault for managing files but again rejected of licensing costs
- use git version control but rejected because of complexity for users and because Autocad file structure does not provide any meaningful way to do merges

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer this for anyone else coming here: there's no such option yet for google drive (as of Jan 2021).

In the end we decided to go with Dropbox for Business which it does